# "I could meet you" vs "I can meet you" & "I would meet you" vs "I will meet you"

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, will-would

Is it true that "could" is generally referred to talk about past possibilities? If so, why?

We say "I could meet you tomorrow". Why can't we just say "I can meet you tomorrow."?

Maybe the answer is that the former sounds more polite?

A follow-up question. Can we say "I could meet you yesterday.", in the present (today), if we didn't met that person yesterday because of some reason? Here we use "could" to talk about past abilities. Now that person asks "When can we possibly meet?" (as we didn't before). In that case, can we say "I could meet you yesterday but now I am busy from mon to fri so probably on sat."?

When we say "I will meet you," we are *certain* that we will meet someone.

I don't understand why we say we "I would meet you". What I understand is that if someone says "I would meet you tomorrow", that basically means "I won't meet you in reality because I have some other stuff to do". So, saying "I would meet" to someone always implies there is a reason why I won't meet them in. If this is so, then when we say "I would meet you," is there any possibility of meeting in reality?

If the answer is yes, then here is a follow-up question, same as for "could".

Can we say "I would meet you yesterday?" in the present (today) if we haven't met that person yesterday because of some reason? We use "would" as past version of "will". Now that person asks again, "As we didn't meet yesterday, when can we possibly meet?". In that case, can we say "I would meet you yesterday but now I am busy from mon to fri so probably on sat.'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I use "can" or "could"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1/when-do-i-use-can-or-could) Also [When should we use “can”, “could”, “will”, “would”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would) and [“Can” vs. “could” in asking a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/can-vs-could-in-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why so few caps? That's just impolite, you know.

Comment: Yeah, there's this thing called a "shift key".  Learn how to use it!

Comment: Please edit this for written English to fix the spelling and capitalization errors. Also please note that in English, you can only have questions, not doubts, about. Those sentences. You are not having a faith crisis in which you disbelieve their putative existence.

Answer (score 1):

*Could* can refer to the past *or* to a hypothetical situation.

> I could meet you tomorrow (if that is convenient for you).
>
> I can meet you tomorrow (the speaker already knows that it suits the other person).
>
> I could *have met* you yesterday if I had known you were free.
>
> I will come tomorrow.
>
> I would come tomorrow if I could (but I have a dentist's appointment).
>
> I would *have met* you yesterday if it had been possible.